# Deleting a specific row in SQL after dynamcic timeframe - PHP, MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Hey so i need a way to remove a row that is connected to a user after a dynamic time. Eg: Insert that your doing something for 15 minutes, after that 15 minutes i want to delete that row automatically.

There will be lots of rows (users doing stuff) in the database and i need them to all be removed after a custom time for each that is set by the user.

How would i go about this!

Thanks in advannce

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need 2 things.

1. a self_destruct_at or equivalent field that is a datetime.  That will be set on creating the record.
2. a worker process to go through ever X minutes (probably 1) and delete the  comments that are older than the current time and the created_at + self_destruct_at time

Comment: In order to reduce calculations required, compute the precise `seft_destruct`-time in step 1 (when creating the record) and in step 2 only compare current time to `self_destruct`.